# How to speed up matplotlib 3d chart rendering?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib in python to create a 3d graph with plot_trisurf, graph is a list of roughly 60,000 points in tuples (X, Y, Z)
However when I run the program the time to render the graph is roughly 10/15 seconds, is there a way to speed this up?
My code is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#create figure
fig = plot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#plot points on graph
X, Y, Z = zip(*graph)
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)
plot.show()
```

Comment: do you really need to plot60,000 points ? Since it's a display, a 1000 ones usually suffice.

Comment: I did think of that, how much faster would it be do you reckon?

Comment: There is a triangulation step in `plot_trisurf` which scales worse than O(n), so I would expect significant speed up.  On the other hand guessing about these things is always a bad idea ;)